# How is the amount earned in a mission determined?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I noticed that sometimes I get the double amount when I'm the host of a mission.
So, I thought that the host always received more money than the others.

Yesterday, I'm pretty sure I was the host and I did get the same amount of the other players.

In one mission, 3 people got 4500 and 2 others got 9000. And I'm still pretty sure that I was the host. I was one of the 3...

Does the amount of money rewarded is affected by the "performance" of the player (I don't have a definition of performance in that case) ?

Comment: That doesn't make sense.... I play with a group of guys and all but one of them have a higher level then myself.(I'm in the 70s and they are up in the 100s) Yet some how I always end up getting paid more on most missions, and yes I have played all of these missions several times and with the same group almost everytime. Sometimes, I'm the host sometimes, I'm not. I've tried to find this answer in several different online forums, but it seems like no one really knows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, performance is not a factor. I believe you received 50% of the normal payout because you completed the mission already.

Once you have completed a mission, you only receive 50% of the cash reward for subsequent completions. I believe this only occurs when the party votes to replay the last mission during the voting screen.

So, the other 2 players probably were not present for your previous plays on that mission and therefore got all $9000.

As turbo pointed out, you will also receive half payout if you do not meet the required level of the mission.

Comment: You also get half if you are not the required level, eg you join a level 50 mission as a level 45, you will only get half the pay until you reach that level and beat it again.

Answer (score 0):

On the mission per pressure. On average iwould receive 9000 but if I were to walk the boardwalk and kill civilians by punching them. I normally get around 16000 to 18000 no matter how. Many times I would replay the mission